# Error in connecting database after updating Node JS runtime version

Tags: postgresql, aws-lambda, pg

I have updated an old written Lambda to run on NodeJS 14 from Node 12. It is using the npm package "pg" to connect to Postgresql database. Earlier, it was working fine but now, it is showing the following error:

> self signed certificate in certificate chain
> at TLSSocket.onConnectSecure (_tls_wrap.js:1515:34)
> at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:400:28)
> at TLSSocket.emit (domain.js:475:12)
> at TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:937:8)
> at TLSWrap.ssl.onhandshakedone (_tls_wrap.js:709:12) {   code: 'SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN'

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

After a lot of research, when nothing worked for me, one of my colleagues found a solution (which actually I had already tried) and it worked for us. He set the following environment variable for the corresponding Lambda function:

> NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0

BTW, it was in addition to the suggestions on the official web page of the NPM package pg at https://node-postgres.com/guides/upgrading#upgrading-to-80

Comment: This is unsafe and should not be used. To fix it correctly, specify your custom certificate explicitly as shown in the manual https://node-postgres.com/features/ssl. If you are using a corporate proxy, that will be your proxy cert.